# Switching between multiple depth textures on single FBO

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, fbo, depth-buffer

I am creating a deferred renderer and trying to achieve this using FBOs. First I used 3 different FBOs (gbuffer, lbuffer and "screen") and it worked. However, It was very poor in performance. I read [here](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/presentations/2005/GDC/OpenGL_Day/OpenGL_FrameBuffer_Object.pdf) that it is much faster to just use ONE FBO and switch textures using glFramebufferTexture2D.

The problem with this technique is that I get tons of unexplained and unpredictable behaviour from the depth textures (I am doing depth peeling and therefore switching between two depth textures). It seems that every time I switch from depth texture A to texture B, A gets cleared to zero and visa versa.

Does anyone know if there is an issue with using glFramebufferTexture2D to switch depth textures for the same FBO? I am using gDebugger for checking the textures.

I am developing in Visual C++ 2010.